# Getting date from NSNumber

Tags: ios, date, time, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have date in value (long)1396267211 - How can I get NSDate from it? I think that it is a NSTimeINterval but I am not sure.

Comment: You should start by being sure what the number means. Does it mean `03 / 31 / 14 @ 12:00:11pm UTC` ?

Comment: just put NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:1396267211];
and you will get your ans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[yourNumber doubleValue]]
```

Double value to make sure it follows NSTimeInterval precision.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `NSInteger` to `NSDate` as

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:1396267211];
NSLog(@"Date is : %@",d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1396267211];
NSLog(@"%@", myDate);
```

Output in console

```
2014-03-31 12:00:11 +0000
```